# Scaling of the shear rate with pipe diameter

Tags: fluid-dynamics, molecular-dynamics, soft-matter

In a laminar flow regime the flow profile in a pipe should be given by:
$$ v(r) = \frac{\Delta p}{4 \eta l} (R^2-r^2)$$

If we assume that the radial shear rate is a meaningful indicator for the deformation of a macromolecule swimming in the pipe we get:

$$ \dot{\gamma}(r) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} = -\frac{\Delta p \cdot 2r}{4 \eta l} $$

Evaluating this expression between $0$ and $R$ makes it seem like the shear rate increases with pipe diameter which is counter-intuitive to me. More specifically if define something like an average shear rate:
$$ \langle \dot{\gamma} \rangle = \int_{r=0}^{R} \int_{\phi=0}^{2 \pi} P(r,\phi) |\dot{\gamma}(r)| r dr d\phi $$

With uniform distribution of the macromolecule $\frac{1}{R^2 \pi}$ we would get:
$$ \langle \dot{\gamma} \rangle =  \frac{\Delta p R}{3 \eta l}$$

Which scales linearly with the pipe diameter. Now I know that the distribution of a particle in a pipe $P(r,\phi)$ is not uniform in the presence of flow (I think this is called inertial migration). However when we did some simulations the distribution was similar when doubling the diameter $R \rightarrow 2R$ and we did indeed observe a doubling of the shear rate computed as an average like stated above, with the radial distribution $P(r)$ looking "a bit like gaussian" distributions depending on the pressure difference.

It is completely counterintuitive to me that something would be affected by a higher shear rate when increasing the pipe diameter. Where did we go wrong?

**Context:**
This question bugs me since my time in university. We were doing some investigations on the posibilty to unfold large globular polymers/proteins under shear, which seemed like a controversial topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the pressure drop is constant, which it is not (at constant volumetric flow rate).  For a given volumetric flow rate Q, the shear rate at the wall is $$\gamma_w=\frac{32Q}{\pi D^3}$$and you can see that this decreases with increasing diameter.

Comment: Thanks this is an interesting viewpoint. However doesn't this depend on the use case? If we e.g. assume we can only generate a certain pressure drop across a pore/pipe, we would still achieve higher shear rates if we increase the diameter wouldn't we?

Comment: For fixed pressure drop, the volumetric throughput rate increases as the 4th power of the diameter, so, if you increase the diameter at constant pressure drop, the shear rate increases (as a result of the large increase in volumetric flow rate)>

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Your last sentence really gave some Intuition to this, thank you!